# Collection of Forms inside Collection of Forms Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-forms

I have three entities `Post Caroussel` and `CarousselImg`.
Which the `Carousel` entity is related to Post entity with `post_id`
and `CarousselImg` entity is related to Caroussel entity with `caroussel_id`.
The relations many-to-one and one-to-many are generated by doctrine.

The problem is when I try to add post that contains caroussel [contain carousselimg].

> The property "carousselImgs" in class "AppBundle\Entity\Caroussel" can be defined with the methods "addCarousselImg()", "removeCarousselImg()" but the new value must be an array or an instance of \Traversable, "AppBundle\Entity\CarousselImg" given.

Here is my caroussel part in Post Type

```
->add('caroussels',CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type'   => CarousselType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'delete_empty'=>true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'prototype' => true,
                'entry_options'  => array(
                    'attr'      => array('class' => 'caroussels-box')
                ),
            )
        )
```

Here is my carousselImg part in Caroussel Type

```
$builder->add('title')->add('carousselImgs', new CarousselImgType());
```

thanks for the help

```html
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * CarousselImg
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="caroussel_img")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\CarousselImgRepository")
 */
class CarousselImg
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="imgUrl", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $imgUrl;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Caroussel", inversedBy="carousselImgs" )
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="caroussel_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */

    private $caroussel;
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set imgUrl
     *
     * @param string $imgUrl
     * @return CarousselImg
     */
    public function setImgUrl($imgUrl)
    {
        $this->imgUrl = $imgUrl;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get imgUrl
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getImgUrl()
    {
        return $this->imgUrl;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     * @return CarousselImg
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set caroussel
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Caroussel $caroussel
     * @return CarousselImg
     */
    public function setCaroussel(\AppBundle\Entity\Caroussel $caroussel = null)
    {
        $this->caroussel = $caroussel;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get caroussel
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Caroussel 
     */
    public function getCaroussel()
    {
        return $this->caroussel;
    }
}
```

```html
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
/**
 * Caroussel
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="caroussel")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\CarousselRepository")
 */
class Caroussel
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Post", inversedBy="caroussels" )
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="post_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */

    private $post;
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CarousselImg", mappedBy="caroussel", cascade={"persist"} )
     */
    private $carousselImgs;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->carousselImgs = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }
    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     * @return Caroussel
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Set post
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Post $post
     * @return Caroussel
     */
    public function setPost(\AppBundle\Entity\Post $post = null)
    {
        $this->post = $post;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get post
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Post 
     */
    public function getPost()
    {
        return $this->post;
    }

    /**
     * Add carousselImgs
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\CarousselImg $carousselImgs
     * @return Caroussel
     */
    public function addCarousselImg(\AppBundle\Entity\CarousselImg $carousselImgs)
    {
        $carousselImgs->setCaroussel($this);
        $this->carousselImgs[] = $carousselImgs;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove carousselImgs
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\CarousselImg $carousselImgs
     */
    public function removeCarousselImg(\AppBundle\Entity\CarousselImg $carousselImgs)
    {
        $this->carousselImgs->removeElement($carousselImgs);
    }

    /**
     * Get carousselImgs
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getCarousselImgs()
    {
        return $this->carousselImgs;
    }
}
```

```html
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Post
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="post")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\PostRepository")
 */
class Post
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="subTitle", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $subTitle;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="thumble", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $thumble;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="postFirstImg", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $postFirstImg;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="activeOrNot", type="integer")
     */
    private $activeOrNot;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $type;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="posts")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $category;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Seo", inversedBy="posts", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="seo_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */

    protected $seo;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Video", mappedBy="post", cascade={"persist"} )
     */

    private $videos;
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Citation", mappedBy="post", cascade={"persist"} )
     */
    private $citations;
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Caroussel", mappedBy="post", cascade={"persist"} )
     */
    private $caroussels;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->videos = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->citations = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->caroussels = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Set subTitle
     *
     * @param string $subTitle
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setSubTitle($subTitle)
    {
        $this->subTitle = $subTitle;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get subTitle
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getSubTitle()
    {
        return $this->subTitle;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set thumble
     *
     * @param string $thumble
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setThumble($thumble)
    {
        $this->thumble = $thumble;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get thumble
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getThumble()
    {
        return $this->thumble;
    }

    /**
     * Set postFirstImg
     *
     * @param string $postFirstImg
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setPostFirstImg($postFirstImg)
    {
        $this->postFirstImg = $postFirstImg;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get postFirstImg
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPostFirstImg()
    {
        return $this->postFirstImg;
    }

    /**
     * Set activeOrNot
     *
     * @param integer $activeOrNot
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setActiveOrNot($activeOrNot)
    {
        $this->activeOrNot = $activeOrNot;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get activeOrNot
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getActiveOrNot()
    {
        return $this->activeOrNot;
    }

    /**
     * Set type
     *
     * @param string $type
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setType($type)
    {
        $this->type = $type;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get type
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getType()
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    /**
     * Set category
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Category $category
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setCategory(\AppBundle\Entity\Category $category = null)
    {
        $this->category = $category;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get category
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Category 
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    /**
     * Set seo
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Seo $seo
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setSeo(\AppBundle\Entity\Seo $seo = null)
    {
        $this->seo = $seo;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get seo
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Seo 
     */
    public function getSeo()
    {
        return $this->seo;
    }


    /**
     * Add videos
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Video $videos
     * @return Post
     */
    public function addVideo(\AppBundle\Entity\Video $videos)
    {
        $videos->setPost($this);
        $this->videos[] = $videos;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove videos
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Video $videos
     */
    public function removeVideo(\AppBundle\Entity\Video $videos)
    {
        $this->videos->removeElement($videos);
    }

    /**
     * Get videos
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getVideos()
    {
        return $this->videos;
    }

    /**
     * Add citations
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Citation $citations
     * @return Post
     */
    public function addCitation(\AppBundle\Entity\Citation $citations)
    {
        $citations->setPost($this);
        $this->citations[] = $citations;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove citations
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Citation $citations
     */
    public function removeCitation(\AppBundle\Entity\Citation $citations)
    {
        $this->citations->removeElement($citations);
    }

    /**
     * Get citations
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getCitations()
    {
        return $this->citations;
    }
    public function __toString(){
        return $this->type;
    }

    /**
     * Add caroussels
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Caroussel $caroussels
     * @return Post
     */
    public function addCaroussel(\AppBundle\Entity\Caroussel $caroussels, \AppBundle\Entity\CarousselImg $carousselImg)
    {
        $caroussels->setPost($this);
        $carousselImg->setCaroussel($caroussels);
        $this->caroussels[] = $caroussels;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove caroussels
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Caroussel $caroussels
     */
    public function removeCaroussel(\AppBundle\Entity\Caroussel $caroussels)
    {
        $this->caroussels->removeElement($caroussels);
    }

    /**
     * Get caroussels
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getCaroussels()
    {
        return $this->caroussels;
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `new CarousselImgType()` with `CarousselImgType::class`. The second parameter of the `add` method expects to have the type of your field, not the object.

Edit: You are giving a `CarousselImg` to your `Caroussel` instead of a collection of `CarousselImg`. You should do something like that in your Caroussel Type:

```
->add('title')
->add('carousselImgs', CollectionType::class, array(
    'entry_type'   => CarousselImgType::class,
    //...
)
```

Comment: hello thanks for the answer but i didnot work same error

Comment: Can we have the full code of the classes _CarousselType_ and _AppBundle\Entity\Caroussel_  please?